# How to get a direct output from a running process?

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, command

I've been trying to read lines of console output from a command in realtime, but I've only been able to get it after the process has ended. How could I run a command and get the output as it runs?

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
public OutputStream executeCommand(String command) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);    
        Process p = pb.start();
        OutputStream ops = p.getOutputStream();
        return ops;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the code below can throw an IOException.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
            Process process = runtime.exec("Your command") ;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())) ;
            String line = null ;
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```